# Redirect old URL to new subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a blog under `example.com/blog`, but now I changed to `blog.example.com`, which redirects to the same old folder.

I don't want users to access directly the old URL, so, redirecting /blog to blog. How can I do it?

I would prefer using .htaccess. Current is WordPress default:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you post your current .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or
You could do something like this that would check from the main domain - This checks if you are already at blog.example.com otherwise it will redirect.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.example\.com$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.example.com [L,NC,R=301]
```